# What are the nuances of observing a "property" that's actually derived by a getter?

Tags: javascript, polymer, ecmascript-6

I am using PolymerJS.

It looks like observing a property that is derived by a `getter` works.

For example, the following code seems to work:

```
<div>Direct binding to property: {{internalData.value}}</div>
<div>Binding to computed value: {{computedValue}}</div>
<div>Binding to observed value: {{observedValue}}</div>

<script>
  var externalData = {
    get value() {
      return 'static value';
    }
  };

  Polymer('my-element', {
    internalData: externalData,
    computed: {
      computedValue: 'internalData.value'
    },
    observe: {
      'internalData.value': 'valueChanged'
    },
    valueChanged: function() {
      this.observedValue = this.internalData.value;
    }
  });
</script>
```

However, what if my `getter` defines something more complex? I have found that if the `getter` returns a new value on every call, then attempting this sort of binding will result my browser tab crashing (this is Chrome 39, so I believe it's a result of native object observation).

For example:

```
var externalData = {    
  get changingValue() {
    return Math.random();
  }
}
```

Why is this? What else should I be worried about if I attempt this pattern?

Here's a more-complete rundown of the different permutations of the problem:

http://jsbin.com/reder/28/edit?html,output

Note, btw, that this issue could come up more commonly than you think. If one returns an Object from a getter, it's easy to accidentally create a new one on each access, e.g.:

```
var externalData = {    
  get changingValue() {
    return { foo: 'bar' };
  }
}
```

Comment: I think your Polymer is missing a closing `)`

Comment: Thanks, Sterling. Amended.

Comment: I'd guess your access of `this.internalData.changingValue` inside of the `changingValueChanged` listener causes a new value to be generated, which causes an infinite loop of change events. Accessing the data and changing the data are always coincident, so if changing the data causes an access on the data, there will be an infinite loop. If your `changingValueChanged` function doesn't access `changingValue`, it seems there's no infinite loop. However, that doesn't seem to be the whole story, because accessing `changingValue` from the console doesn't fire the change listener.

Comment: Here's an example that will crash your browser much more slowly, by putting the access inside of a `setTimeout`: http://jsbin.com/gotobanipo/1/edit?html,console,output

Answer (score 2):

Not a complete answer, but he's a start:

Consider when `changingValueChanged` runs. It runs every time `changingValue` changes.

Consider when `changingValue` changes. It changes every time it is accessed.

The final piece to understand the crash is that `changingValueChanged` accesses the `changingValue`:

```
this.observedChangingValue = this.internalData.changingValue;
```

When accessing the value for that assignment, you change the value and casue the listener to run again, which repeats forever.

It would appear that you cannot meaningfully observe a value that will *always* be different on each access. Not mention that trying to capture the value of that variable after you know it has changed is meaningless: the variable is functionally a generator. You can't ask the variable what value it just had, because it can only give you new values. On the other hand, you *can* observe a getter-based variable that simply changes occasionally, because it changes its value based on something other than the act of accessing the value.

If you change your listener to do something not related to the variable (e.g., simply do `console.log("hello")`) and never access `this.internalData.changingValue`, there is no infinite loop. Note that the new observed value is in the first argument provided to the change listener, so you can safely get the value that way . However, that's not the value that is ultimately displayed on the page by Polymer; it appears that Polymer does yet another access to read the value to put it into the DOM.

However, note that the change listener doesn't appear to run when you access `externalData.changingValue` in the console, but it *does* run when accessing `externalData`, which shows all the properties of the object.

I can't speak to why the `compute` property crashes the page, because I don't know what that does.

Comment: Close to comprehensive. Thanks much for the detailed answer. It makes sense that a getter that's a generator will also get into an infinite call cycle with computed value as well, since as you say simply using it in the template will trigger a new access on the getter. If I remove the use of {{computedChangingValue}} in my example, it does indeed run without crashing the browser tab.

Note, btw, that this could come up more commonly in this pattern than you think. If one returns an Object from a getter, it's easy to accidentally create a new one on each access.

I'll add a note about this.